# Unable to get camera video with ubuntu

Tags: video, vlc, webcam, camera

I am trying to display the camera video with VLC `vlc v4l2:///dev/video0`  but so far all my attempts failed.
I tried different SO answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091222/how-to-capture-video-stream-in-vlc).

But the error I am getting is still the same:

> cannot start streaming: Input/output error
>
> not a radio tuner device
>
> open of `v4l2:///dev/video0' failed

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded to make my cams work. Actually I was using Ubuntu in Virtual Box. And to display the cam streaming in VLC one needs to download Virtual Box Extension Pack [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). As a result, there is a new entry `"Webcams"` option in the Devices menu when the virtual machine is running. One can select the cam to use with this option.

Comment: thx man! I had the same issue and it seems to work using Virtual Box Extension Pack